# JQuery ON not working

Tags: jquery

I've practically spent more than 4 hours on figuring out what's wrong with what I'm doing. Kindly help me out why this works:

```
    $("div.spinedit i.modify-counter").on('click', function() {
        alert("here");
    });
```

and this does not:

```
    $(document).on("click", "div.spinedit i.modify-counter", function(e) {
        alert("here");
    });
```

The first code only works with the items  generated along with the page, what I need is for it to work on AJAX-generated elements as well.

Comment: Remember in the future, posting a (non-)working fiddle is always easier to help you out :)

Comment: You should provide relevant HTML markup too. Obviously, the HTML you get from ajax is not the same

Comment: IT IS WORKING http://jsfiddle.net/t3pwn/

Comment: @jtheman have you really took some time reading the question?

Comment: I was about to copy my code to jsfiddle, but @Hiral is faster than my copy-paste ninjutsu

Comment: @macinville but your error seems that the html returned from ajax doesn't contains elements `i.modify-counter` wrapped inside `div.spinedit`. Check it!

Comment: @silentw Well yes: http://jsfiddle.net/t3pwn/1/

Comment: @A.Wolff that's not the issue, simply you first need to grab the first parent that is already on the page (not dynamic) and then you can assign the click on the dynamic child of the static parent. Check my answer.

Comment: @A.Wolff When I used the second script, even the alert won't get triggered in the elements generated with the page load, so I didn't find it necessary to submit HTML markup of the AJAX return. But I'll keep that in mind :)

Comment: @silentw sure it the issue! The only one i can think about...

Comment: @macinville that's simply impossible!

Comment: @silentw whether it's the first parent, or the nth parent, it shouldn't matter. `document` is a global parent to every element so the selector should have worked provided the markup is as the OP has stated. Without physically seeing it, there's no way to verify.

Comment: @A.Wolff I agree, that's why I have to ask help from experts here like you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably descendant elements are added to the document at a later time. **By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.**

Following code should work.

```
$(document).on("click", "i.modify-counter", function(e) {
    alert("here");
});
```

OR

```
$("div.spinedit").on("click", "i.modify-counter", function(e) {
    alert("here");
});
```

[Read more information here.](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: I don't understand why what he currently has doesn't work though. div.spinedit is also a child of the document, therefore the selector should catch it.

Comment: I just want to know what's wrong with OP's code. can you please explain.?

Comment: I'd imagine that the issue is he's got 2 selectors

Comment: from the docs: "A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that will call the handler. If the selector is null or omitted, the handler is always called when it reaches the selected element." the OP posted a selector string, did he not?

Comment: wow it worked. I wonder why the first code works, I just used the same selector. Anyway, thanks for your very fast answer :)

Comment: @everyone that doesn't know what is wrong with OP's code, check my answer.

Comment: @Brad Technically speaking, it is one large multi-part selector. I'm with the rest of these guys though. Not sure why this works and the OP's code does not. Makes no sense. I'm not completely convinced the the `i.modify-counter` data comes back wrapped in `div.spinedit`.

Comment: @silentw that doesn't explain or show why his code doesn't work.

Comment: @all I hope I answer all queries.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
$("div.spinedit").on('click',  "i.modify-counter", function() {
        alert("here");
});
```

or

```
$(document).on('click',  "i.modify-counter", function() {
            alert("here");
});
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, grab the parent element that is static (I guess that's the `.spinedit`), then assign click event to every element `.modify-counter` that's inside of it.

Like this:

```
$('div.spinedit').on('click', 'i.modify-counter', function(event) {
    alert("Hello, I'm working!");
});
```

Comment: But so OP's code using delegation at document level should work too

Comment: @A.Wolff you're correct, after testing it out, it should work correctly, don't know what the issue was (probably the issue wasn't in that particular code but something else before).

Comment: Or maybe there was a hidden character in his code that got copied in from somewhere

Comment: @KevinB are you referring e.g to jsfiddle?! ;)

Answer (score 1):

With your first example....

```
$("div.spinedit i.modify-counter").on('click', function() {
    alert("here");
});
```

You are finding all elements when the page is loaded and binding the event handler once to each of these elements. If a DOM element is not present at that one point in time is not going to fire the event handler... how could it fire the handler if it wasnt around when you set it???

```
$(document).on("click", "div.spinedit i.modify-counter", function(e) {
    alert("here");
});
```

Here, you are finding the document upon page load and binding a click handler to it. You are **not** binding a click handler to the `i.modify-counter` elements. However, the second parameter (e.g. `"div.spinedit i.modify-counter"`) indicates to the handler that it should only fire when

1. the item that was clicked was a child element of the document, and,
2. the item that was clicked matches the selector that you passed in.

This is a subtle but **big** difference. Because the handler is on the `document`, there is no need to rebind the click handler when new AJAX elements are added later... because the handler isnt on those elements.

Each time anything under `document` is clicked, the handler will evaluate if it matches that selector. If it does, then the event is fired.

Answer (score 0):

'on' method will not work on dynamically generated content. Instead - you need to attach 'on' method to static parent, and pass your actuall, dynamically inserted tag as a second parameter.